# sqlite3 error "attempt to write a readonly database"

Tags: android, python, sqlite, ubuntu-14.04

I'm sure this will be a silly question for those who know python but I'm trying to debug a python script and I can't find out something.

I'm getting the following error:

> (sqlite3.OperationalError) attempt to write a readonly database [SQL: u'INSERT INTO samples (file_size, file_type, md5, crc32, sha1, sha256, sha512, ssdeep) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)']

I know that to fix this what I have to do is to change the DB access to write, but I don't know where this DB is located. The DB is created in the script this way:

```
db = Database()
```

And these are the imports:

```
import argparse
import fnmatch
import logging
import os
import random
import sys

try:
    import requests
    HAVE_REQUESTS = True
except ImportError:
    HAVE_REQUESTS = False
```

And the line in which I'm getting the error is the following one

```
db.add_path(...);
```

This file is part of the Cuckoo Droid project, specifically is the script to submit a APK to be analyzed. I don't know if the DB is located in the Android emulator or in the host machine. If so, I would like to know where that DB could be located in order to change the privileges of the DB to give write access. Any help would be grate, thanks.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The DB I was looking for is located inside cuckoo/ directory. Specifically inside db/ folder. To fix my problem what I made was to change privileges of the folder recursively:

```
sudo chmod 777 -R db
```

Comment: Doing recursive chmod 777 is very dangerous.
It should be noted that this is a dangerous thing to do as it effectively removes all permission-based security of all files and subdirectories and will break e.g. ssh!